# scala macro error when compile

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I would like to use scala macros for experiment. But got errors, when i use macro.

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Macro {
  import scala.reflect.macros.Context

  def metImpl(c : Context) (s : c.Expr[String]) = {
    import c.universe._

    reify {
     ()
    }
  }
 }


 object A {

   def met(k: String):Unit = macro Macro.metImpl //this error

 }
```

Error:

```
test.scala:19: error: macro implementation must be in statically accessible object
def met(k: String):Unit = macro Macro.metImpl
```

Why?

Comment: For me it says: 17:20 ~/Projects/210x/sandbox (2.10.x)$ s
Test.scala:18: error: macro implementation has wrong shape:
 required: (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(k: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit]
 found   : (c: scala.reflect.macros.Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Unit]
parameter names differ: k != s
   def met(k: String):Unit = macro Macro.metImpl //this error
                                         ^
one error found

Comment: What version of Scala do you use? Could you post the reproduction as a standalone sbt project on github, so that I could take a look?

Comment: ou, i use 2.11.0-M2 version

Comment: @EugeneBurmako it only one file with this objects. And when `scala test.scala` i get this error

Comment: Is it `scalac test.scala` or `scala test.scala`?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako scala test.scala

Comment: @EugeneBurmako I run it in SBT ENV and it work. Thanks.